# ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. IEEE

Tags: ieeeconf

I have a issue with my code , i have seen similar posts but nothing helped, i am using biber % and the pdf+bilatex+pdflatex+pdf in Texmaker , any sugestions?

Thank you

Code:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
xxxx\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage[backend=biber, bibencoding=utf8,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\let\proof\relax
\let\endproof\relax
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

Error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
```

Comment: delete the `xxxx` on line two, you can not have text there.

Comment: you are correct! thank you @DavidCarlisle